# angular 8 a variable is modified in onchanges event , but when i want to access it i find that is not changed

Tags: angular, input

i have a application in angular , and i have a component with custem property  "modeInsert", and i detect change of this property in ngOnChanges() event , like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild,  OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-cv',
  templateUrl: './update-cv.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-cv.component.css']
})
export class UpdateCVComponent implements OnInit ,OnChanges {

  constructor() { }

  mode:boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changeRecord: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(typeof changeRecord.modeInsert !== 'undefined'){
      this.mode=changeRecord.modeInsert.currentValue;
      console.log("changeRecord._modeInsert :"+this.mode);
    }
  }

  @Input() modeInsert: boolean;

  @ViewChild('closebuttonUpdateCV',{static: false}) closebuttonUpdateCV;
  onUpdateCV(cv){
    console.log(" onUpdateCV mode ="+this.mode)
    if(this.mode){
      console.log(" mode = ajout")
    }else {
      console.log(" mode = modif")
    }
    this.closebuttonUpdateCV.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

,This variable changes its value in Onchanges Event, but when I try to reach its value, I find that it has not changed, like in methode onUpdateCV(cv).

Comment: Why don't you use `this.modeInsert` in `onUpdateCV` instead of `this.mode`? I don't see the point in assigning an input variable to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks, I did not do this, because this.modeInsert does not change its value except in onchage,

Comment: Then something else is wrong with your setup. Could you provide a stackblitz that replicates the problem.

Comment: @fridoo when i use a component in defirent place this proble Appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I put two copies of this component, one in the menu and the other in another component, so when I called may compenet from the other component, I would have called the version on the menu , and the variable this.mode is undifained.
and this is the templet of may component, is a modal form:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalEtatCivile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="ModalLabelEtatCivile" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabelEtatCivile">
           
        </h5>
        <button type="button" #closebuttonUpdateCV class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
        aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>


        
      </div>
      <form #fcv="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdateCV(fcv.value)">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">nom:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nom"   name="nom" ngModel>
 
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organisation">prenom:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="prenom"   name="prenom" ngModel>
 
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organisation">Etat civile :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Etat civile" name="etatcivile"  ngModel>
          
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organisation">Adress :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Adress" name="adress" ngModel>
    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organisation">Email :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"  name="email" ngModel>
  
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organisation">Tel :</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tel." name="tel" ngModel>
         
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sauvgarder</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but in this case what i do for caling the copy what i ned

Answer (score 0):

You will get current and previous values in ngOnChanges

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      for (let propName in changes) {
        let chng = changes[propName];
        let cur  = JSON.stringify(chng.currentValue);
        let prev = JSON.stringify(chng.previousValue);
      }
    }
```

Comment: thinks, the problem is not in nfOnChanges() it work perfectly an this.mode chans his value , but wen i execute onupdatecv() this.mode is undifined

Comment: Remove the extra object added for mode. Use the same modeInsert variable and try again